Identify a 1980's thriller in which a family moves into a country house and then their young son disappears
I am looking for a movie I saw in England in 1987 in which a family moves into a country house and then their young son disappears.
After a while the family starts hearing strange sounds which they interpret as paranormal phenomena related to the child disappearance, including calls from the boy.
They eventually hire specialists on paranormal stuff who take the search to increasingly fantastic directions.  Eventually they discover

that their son was in fact trapped in their basement, which no one knew about, during a party when someone drops some heavy bars against the basement door.   However, since the whole ordeal took several days, the child is found dead.


Was this a movie, or maybe an episode of an anthology show?

As far as I can remember this was a movie by itself.  It was screened in the Warwick University Arts Centre in 1987.

Are you absolutely sure that you saw this in 1987? The plot that you are describing is an exact match for The Orphanage (2007).
Laura returns to her childhood orphanage with her husband and adopted son, Simón, intending to reopen it as a home for disabled children. Simón goes missing, and Laura hears eerie sounds during the night. She conducts a séance, revealing the tragic deaths of the orphanage’s former children.
In the end, Laura finds Simón’s body hidden in a secret basement. A flashback shows him entering the basement, and some poles fall against the door, jamming it shut. His cries for help were the calls that she had been hearing in the night.

"From an original screenplay...". It's not a remake, as far as I can tell.

Yep, that was my first thought - could it have been a remake? However, I can find no evidence of this.

Thanks very much for your answer. I just watched the youtube trailer and it does look like this is it.  I am trying to get some more information in order to confirm it once and for all, and if so I'll come back here to describe the results.  In this case I'll also have to understand how can I be 20 years off regarding the year I watched this movie!

Yep, you nailed it!
